# Group by Id for order Status

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

```
OrderId KId OrderStatus
1   2042    2
2   2042    2
3   2042    2
4   2042    2
5   2042    2
53  2152    2
7   2069    1
8   2042    2
9   2042    4
10  2042    1
24  2043    2
```

I have a Orders Table with KitchenId as KId , OrderId and Status 
I want to group this table for showing report as KId , TotalOrders, Delivered ,Accepted , Rejected 
based on OrderStatus = 2 Accepted , 4 Delivered , 1 rejected

My desired Result is like below

```
KId    Total Order  Accepted Rejected Delivered 
2042     8           6          1         1 
2043     1           1          0         0
```

Comment: Why are 2152 and 2069 excluded from the result?

Answer (score 3):

Try the following. Here is the [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ebe33d/1).

```
select
    KId,
    count(KId) as total_orders,
    sum(case when OrderStatus = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as Accepted,
    sum(case when OrderStatus = 4 then 1 else 0 end) as Rejected,
    sum(case when OrderStatus = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as Delivered
from orders
group by
    KId
```

Output:

```
| KId  | total_orders | accepted | rejected | delivered |
| ---- | ------------ | -------- | -------- | --------- |
| 2042 | 8            | 6        | 1        | 1         |
| 2043 | 1            | 1        | 0        | 0         |
| 2069 | 1            | 0        | 0        | 1         |
| 2152 | 1            | 1        | 0        | 0         |
```

Answer (score 0):

You coud use conditional aggregation and count distinct for be sure for ordere count

```
    select KId
        , count(distinct orderId) total 
        , sum( when OrderStatus = 2 then 1 else 0 end) Accepted 
        , sum( when OrderStatus = 4 then 1 else 0 end) Delivered 
        , sum( when OrderStatus = 1 then 1 else 0 end) Rejected 
    from my_ttable  
    group by  KId
```